# MS Access lookup and update a field from another

Tags: ms-access, vba

I receive data from a barcode scanner like the below.  I need to populate the BoxID (type = integer) from the ID field.

[image]

This is the desired result - the ID uniquely identifies the box: 
[image]

Comment: This will require VBA that opens and manipulates a recordset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that data is consistent, consider:

```
Sub SetBoxID()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, intID As Integer
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID")
While Not rs.EOF
    If rs!Type = "Box" Then 
       intID = rs!ID
    ElseIf rs!Type = "Desp" Then
        rs.Edit
        rs!BoxID = intID
        rs.Update
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
End Sub
```